# Lower the Video Quality for Higher FPS When Live Filtering Using CIImage

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, opengl-es

I'm trying to doing live camera filter like Instagram and Path. Since I'm not skilled enough to handle OpenGL ES. I use iOS 5's CoreImage instead.

I use this call back method to intercept and filter each frame from the camera:

```
-(void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection {
```

The session preset I use is **AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto**, since I need to take high-quality photos in the end.

If I just present the buffer to screen without any CIImage filtering, the average FPS would reach **26** or even more, which is great.

If I start to apply some CIFilters to the image data, the FPS would drop to as low as **10** or even lower. The live video would start to look bad.

I understand that Instagram and Path would use OpenGL ES directly rather than wrapped frameworks such as CoreImage, so that they could build more efficient code for GPU rendering. At the same time, I also notice that Instagram actually lowers the sample video quality to further reduce the GPU burden. Below is the screenshot I took when my app (left) and Instagram (right) are both capturing live video. Pay attention to the letter **Z** and **S** in both pictures. You can see that Instagram's video quality is slightly lower than mine.

So right now I'm considering various ways to reduce the live video frame quality. But I really have no idea which way is better. And how should I implement it.

1. Try to reduce this **(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer**'s quality before converting it into a CIImage object.
2. Try to find some APIs from CIImage or CIFilter or CIContext to lower the video frame quality.
3. Try to find some APIs from OpenGL ES to lower the video frame quality.

Again, I don't have any clues now. So any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`AVcaptureSession` has the property `sessionPreset` which allow video quality to set low medium or high.

Below code set quality to medium.

```
[self.mSession setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium];
```

Comment: As I mentioned, I need to use this session to take high quality photos in the end. Besides, the time penalty of dynamically switching presets is huge. Therefore, presets other than AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto is out of the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you're unwilling to lower the video quality (and I think AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto is pretty low anyway), your best bet is either optimizing your filters, or lowering the frame-rate.

You may think, well, I'm already getting a lower frame-rate. However, setting this in advance will optimize the way the frames are dropped. So, if you're getting 10fps now, try setting the max frame rate to, say 15, and you might just get that 15. 15fps is plenty good for a preview.

(I've worked on [Flare](http://getflare.com), on one of the most demanding apps out there itun.es/iLQ3bR.)